# Selectize js submitting only last selected item

Tags: javascript, php, html, selectize.js

I'm currently using Selectize.js with a 'select' item and multiple options. My html is something like:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="record-genre">Genre(s):</label>
                    <select name="record_genre" id="record-genre" class="form-control multi-selectize" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Enter genre(s)">
                        <?php foreach ($record_genre_opts as $key => $val): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php echo (in_array($key, $record_genre)) ? "selected" : ''; ?>
                                <?php echo set_select('record_genre', $val); ?>
                            >
                                <?php echo $val; ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

So far so good. The items are being loaded correctly and until this point everything works great. The issue is that when the form is submitted only the last value selected is the one that is available, so if I selected multiple items I'm getting just one:

> ["record_genre"]=>   string(1) "1"

Here's my JS setup:

```
$('.multi-selectize').each(function(){
            //console.log($(this))
            $(this).selectize({})

        })
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. The name of the select item should be record_genre[] since it is declared as a multiple select instead of just record_genre.